# Where does Python Imaging LIbrary Save Objects

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am using the Image.save method from PIL and I cannot find where the file is being placed.  I have done a system search yet still no luck.

My code looks like this:
    print imageObj.save(fileName, "JPEG")

and gives the proper None response to say that it is working.  Any idea where they go and how I can find them?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it opens files in the working directory of your script, wherever that is (unless your file name is an absolute path). What does `os.getcwd()` return in that spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pick a location to save the image when setting the filename variable. 
`filename = "/Users/clifgray/Desktop/filename.jpeg"`
 
`imgObj.save(filename)`

Comment: great! I suppose that should've been intuitive... but I appreciate the quick answer